# opencv how to draw minAreaRect in java

Tags: java, android, opencv

Hi I am trying to draw the rotated rect from minAreaRect but I find only code in python.

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

How to draw it in java?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but recently I had the same problem so I decided to post the answer here.

Unfortunately, the OpenCV version I'm using on Android doesnt have the method `rectangle` that support `RotatedRect` as paramenter. So I had to improvise.

```
    Point points[] = new Point[4];
    rect.points(points);
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        Core.line(init, points[i], points[(i+1)%4], new Scalar(255,255,255));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `drawContours` like this:

```
Point[] vertices = new Point[4];
rotatedRect.points(vertices);
List<MatOfPoint> boxContours = new ArrayList<>();
boxContours.add(new MatOfPoint(vertices));
Imgproc.drawContours(out, boxContours, 0, new Scalar(128, 128, 128), -1);
```

*With this method you could draw the contour and fill it with a solid color (something you can't do if you use `Imgproc.line`).*

Answer (score 2):

I draw the the rotated rect from minAreaRect using the code like this:

```
rRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(mop2f);

        Point[] vertices = new Point[4];  
        rRect.points(vertices);  
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){  
            Imgproc.line(mat, vertices[j], vertices[(j+1)%4], new Scalar(0,255,0));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
MatOfPoint2f points = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point(1, 1), new Point(5, 1), new Point(4, 3), new Point(6, 2));
RotatedRect rrect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(points);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to draw the result contour from minAreaRect