# How to draw a boundingRect with the right rotation angle by using OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I am performing Canny edge detector using Android and Opencv on an image to detect the largest contour, extract it using warpPerspective method then find all objects inside that contour. Everything is working as expected but only for image that isn't rotated.
I am using boundingRect to get the contour and use its coordinates to extract it.

Here my code:

```
   private Mat  detectLargestContour(Mat origMat) {

   // long e1 = Core.getTickCount();

    Mat mGray = new Mat();

    MatOfDouble mu = new MatOfDouble();

    MatOfDouble stddev = new MatOfDouble();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(origMat, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Core.meanStdDev(mGray, mu, stddev);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 30, 80, 3, false);   //FOR HIGH BRIGHTNESS
    //Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 50, 130, 3, false);    // FOR LOW BRIGHTNESS

    Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, mu.get(0, 0)[0], stddev.get(0, 0)[0], 3, false);

    Mat kernell = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9,9));

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

    Imgproc.dilate(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));


    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(mGray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

   //MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

    double largest_area=0;

    Rect rect = new Rect();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size() ; idx++) {

        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx));  //Find the area of contour

        if (a > largest_area) {
            largest_area = a;
            rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(idx));
        }
    }

    if (rect.area() > 100000) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(origMat, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        p1 = new Point(rect.tl().x, rect.tl().y);
        p2 = new Point(rect.tl().x + rect.width, rect.tl().y);
        p3 = new Point(rect.tl().x, rect.tl().y + rect.height);
        p4 = new Point(rect.tl().x + rect.width, rect.tl().y + rect.height);

        card_corners = new ArrayList<>();
        card_corners.add(p1);
        card_corners.add(p3);
        card_corners.add(p4);
        card_corners.add(p2);

        warpedCard =  new Mat(origMat.rows(), origMat.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        final Point p1 = new Point(warpedCard.cols() + marge, warpedCard.rows() + marge);
        final Point p2 = new Point(0 - marge, warpedCard.rows() + marge);
        final Point p3 = new Point(0 - marge, 0 - marge);
        final Point p4 = new Point(warpedCard.cols() + marge, 0 - marge);

        LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>();
        sceneList.addLast(p4);
        sceneList.addLast(p3);
        sceneList.addLast(p2);
        sceneList.addLast(p1);

        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
        scene.fromList(sceneList);

        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
        obj.fromList(card_corners);

        Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene);
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(origMat, warpedCard, homography, new Size(warpedCard.cols(), warpedCard.rows()));

        return warpedCard;
    }

    return origMat;
}
```

It's weird but only boundingRect gave me a stable and performant result but the drawn rectangle doesn't rotate with the found contour.

How can I manage to resolve this issue? Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I changed boundingRect with minAreaRect.

Here is the code

```
  int largest_idx = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size() ; idx++) {

        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx));  //Find the area of contour

        if (a > largest_area) {

            largest_area = a;

            // rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(idx));

            largest_idx = idx;
        }
    }

    MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(largest_idx).toArray() );

    RotatedRect rbox = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new_mat);

    Log.d("rotatedrect_angle", "" + rbox.angle);

    Point points[] = new Point[4];

    rbox.points(points);

    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        Imgproc.line(origMat, points[i], points[(i+1)%4], new Scalar(255,255,255));
    }
```

And here is what I've got: 
[image]

As you can see the detection isn't as accurate as when I used boundingRect.

Comment: Maybe do you need Imgproc.minAreaRect?

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327502/opencv-how-to-draw-minarearect-in-java

Comment: @Nuzhny Thank you sir, I will try this example

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### A Python demo to find and draw a rotatedRect:

```
# 2019/03/01
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942835/3547485

import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread("tmp.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]
rbox = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
pts = cv2.boxPoints(rbox).astype(np.int32)
cv2.drawContours(img, [pts], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("dst.png", img)
```

Useful OpenCV functions(in Python) : cv2.minAreaRect, cv2.boxPoints, cv.2drawContours. You can find corresponding functions in Java.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try this example and give you back updates.

Comment: @Amine The java question about `minAreaRect`, maybe useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327502/opencv-how-to-draw-minarearect-in-java/26026580#26026580

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but line isn't available yet.

Comment: Imgproc.boxPoints needs two parameters , the rotatedrect and Mat of points, I have the rotatedrect, can you please tell me what to put in the mat of points?